# Decimal expansion no calculator

Tags: number-theory

Find the decimal expansion of $\frac{9}{130} $ by finding the periodical and non periodical parts. am i supposed to be looking for the expansion of  $\frac{1}{(9)(130)} $? cause my theorems don't seem to apply unless the top equals one?

Comment: Why do you want to use Legendre symbols?

Comment: it was an exercise that was  suppose to be easy...

Comment: Hint. Try $9/130 = 10/130 - 1/130$. Or just do the long division. The period must be a divisor of $13-1=12$ so you won't have to go too far.

Comment: Every (positive) rational number has an [Egyptian fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_fraction).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{9}{130}
&= \frac{1}{10} \frac{90}{130} \\
&= \frac{1}{10} \left( 0 + \frac{9}{13} \right)
\end{align*}
$$

Since $\frac{9}{13} < 1$, this tells us that $\frac{9}{130} = 0.0\ldots$.

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{9}{13}
&= \frac{1}{10} \frac{90}{13} \\
&= \frac{1}{10} \left( 6 + \frac{12}{13} \right)
\end{align*}
$$

So $\frac{9}{13} = 0.06\ldots$.

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{12}{13}
&= \frac{1}{10} \frac{120}{13} \\
&= \frac{1}{10} \left( 9 + \frac{3}{13} \right)
\end{align*}
$$

So $\frac{9}{130} = 0.069\ldots$. Now you have to figure out when it becomes periodic.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{9}{130}
&=  \frac{9}{130} \frac{76923}{76923}\\
&=  \frac{1}{10} \frac{692307}{999999} 
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:$$\frac{9}{130} = \frac{10-1}{130} = \frac{1}{13} - \frac{1}{130}$$